# .NET Error with Dynamic T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, tableadapter

I am trying to create a TableAdapter in .NET using a stored procedure, but I'm getting an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'".

I have narrowed down the problem in the stored procedure to the following lines:

```
IF @NumRows > 0
    SET @SQL += N' WHERE T1.RowNumber BETWEEN 1 and 10'
ELSE
    SET @SQL += N' WHERE T1.RowNumber > 0'
```

`@NumRows` is an input parameter that defaults to 0.

However, if I remove either of those lines everything works fine (both WHERE clauses work fine by themselves when there is no IF/ELSE statement).  It almost looks like .NET is ignoring the IF/ELSE and attempting to add the WHERE clause twice.

It also works fine if I change it like so:

```
IF @NumRows > 0
    SET @SQL += N''
ELSE
    SET @SQL += N' WHERE T1.RowNumber > 0'
```

One of the WHERE clauses has been removed, and there's no longer a conflict on the .NET side.  So I'm pretty sure it has to do with the 2 WHERE clauses, and not with anything else.

The sproc runs perfectly fine in SQL Server, and it even runs in .NET despite the error if I click "Preview Data".  The only problem is that it won't auto-populate the list of fields, which I need for creating a report.

Has anybody seen this before and have a suggestion?

Comment: what is the value of @SQL before those lines?

Comment: `WHERE T1.RowNumber` is common to both conditions. Try pulling it out and just append the `BETWEEN 1 and 10` and the `> 0` to your dynamic statement.

Comment: .NET has **nothing to do with this**. This is entirely a TSQL question. Does the sproc/TSQL work *by itself* when invoked through SSMS - that is all that matters. At no point does .NET attempt to parse this. It is executed entirely at the SQL server.

Comment: That's the thing... it works perfectly in SSMS and returns the data I expect based on the input parameters I give it. But when I create a TableAdapter in .NET, it can't figure out what fields are in the sproc because it says there is an error near the WHERE keyword.

Comment: The error "..near the keyword WHERE" comes from SQL Server eventhough you're seeing it in your .NET program. Can you post the code where you execute the SQL that you built up? (Assuming that's the location where you see the exception)

Comment: The error is in my DataSet (.xsd) file - the visual designer. Right-click, then go to Add > TableAdapter, set up the database connection, pick the stored procedure, click through to "Finish", and then it shows the error. It still links to the sproc, and can run when I click "Preview Data", but it can't figure out what fields are in the sproc.  I can add the fields manually, of course, but it just seems like a dumb problem that shouldn't exist.

Comment: By the way, I use these stored procs throughout my code just fine - I usually access them through a SqlCommand object, and there's no problem.  In this case, I'm using the sproc for a SSRS report (local), and (as far as I know, kinda new to SSRS), I need to set it up in the DataSet .xsd file and have it populate the field list so the report knows what it is.

Comment: @Phillip most tools have significant problems with interpreting the schema of code that uses dynamic-SQL. You should have been specific that it was the IDE having this problem, not the runtime.

Comment: Sorry, guess I just inferred it was a design-time thing instead of explicitly saying so.  But yes, that's what it looks like to me - an interpretation problem. Would think that by VS2010 they would have gotten it working :)

Comment: @PhillipTheriault Why don't you move your "final answer" into an answer to the question itself?

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the DataSet (`.xsd`) file - the visual designer. Right-click, then go to `Add` **>** `TableAdapter`, set up the database connection, pick the stored procedure, click through to `Finish`, and then it shows the error. It still links to the sproc, and can run when I click `Preview Data`, but it can't figure out what fields are in the sproc. I can add the fields manually, of course, but it just seems like a dumb problem that shouldn't exist.